# Expected behaviour of a non-inverting buffer IC

Tags: buffer, open-drain

I am using an [NL17SZ07](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nl17sz07-d.pdf) buffer w/ open drain. Is it to be expected that I need to pull the output high with a pull-up resistor to have the output behave as expected?

I would have anticipated that the output would step with the input at the supply voltage, without the need for a pull-up. Perhaps it is the open drain that is causing this? It is causing a lag on the rising edge of the output, that can only be helped by lowering the value of the pull-up.

Is this to be anticipated? Perhaps this is the wrong component for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what an "[open drain](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/glossary/definitions.mvp/term/Open-drain/gpk/1174)" output does, so this is to be anticipated.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I will accept your answer when it lets me. Is this in comparison to other buffers that are not open drain?

Comment: Well, yes, it is!

Comment: Haha copy. Thanks. A quick question and answer this time..!

Answer (score 4):

Just to be clear, this is what an "open-collector" or "open-drain" actually is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff7hIb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this. With respect to your diagram, can I ask for your interpretation of the datasheet? Page 3 shows a MOSFET as the functional component. It has VCC linked to the output and drain through a box labelled 'OVC'. What does that mean?

Comment: I'm thinking OVT means Over-Voltage-Tolerant.  If you look at the first page features, it reads "Input/Output Overvoltage Tolerant up to 5.5 V".  Incidentally, if you tried to pull the Open Drain above 5.5V, the excess voltage will probably flow into Vcc, so not a good idea. :)

Comment: Yep I guess you're right..! Though I'm not sure what VCC does any more. Why not just raise the drain to 5V and forget about VCC?

Comment: Out of interest, what is the relevance of the 1 kOhm resistor? I am also reading about a combined PNP/NPN transistor package, but it has builtin biasing resistors diagrammed the same as yours. I can't see how that biasing isn't just a voltage divider to ground. https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2575368.pdf

Comment: Non-ninja edit: On second thought I suppose the VCC is just powering the whole IC and should in theory be unrelated to the MOSFET drain.

Comment: Correct.  An OC or OD can only pull down to 0v.  The 1k resistor is just to ensure that the base/gate is not active when the device powers up.  For a BJT transistor this is superfluous - base *current* turns that on.  But in a MOSFET, gate *voltage* turns that on.  And the gate is essentially a capacitor, so a resistor is required to ensure any voltage there returns to zero while off.  Vcc should be unrelated to the drain, and on many IC's it is.  But on this particular IC, something in the fabrication process (likely a parasitic diode) exists between the drain and Vcc.

Answer (score 2):

An open drain output won't go high without a pull-up.

Answer (score 2):

It's an open drain output, so yes it needs a pullup. Or you can use it to drive a load tied to VCC, like a LED. If you want it to work without pullup, you need a push-pull output.

If you have say 3V3 logic, and you power this chip from 3V3, note its output is 5V tolerant, so you can use a pullup to +5V to do voltage level translation, for example.